# Package doesnt exist error when trying to import my own package to servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, package

im trying to import my own packages to a servlet im making, using tomcat.

The two java files im working with are the servlet (movieServlet.java), and another class im trying to import from a package (Movie.java)

The hierarchy of folders is:

```
classes
|
+--movieServlet.java
|
+--movie
   |
   +--Movie.java
```

movieServlet.java

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import movie.Movie;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/movieServlet"})
public class movieServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Movie Movie = new Movie();
    request.setAttribute("movies", Movie.getAllMovies());

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/movies.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
} 


public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/movieDetails.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
}
```

}

and this is the top of Movie.java (its a long file)

```
package movie;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class Movie implements java.io.Serializable
{
private static DataSource dataSource = null;
private static Connection c = null;

private int id;
private String title;
private String url;
private int year;

public Movie(){}
```

if theres more info needed please ask :), this has been reallllly bugging me.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what type of problem (compilation/runtime) you are facing. Also, do mention the error message when you edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am new here so excuse me if my answer is not perfect. As you have mentioned that you want to import your own package which contains Movie class. I tried to implement all your main methods and it's running perfect and I am getting my value from Movie.java.

**movieServlet.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import movie.Movie;

public class movieServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
              PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
               Movie Movie = new Movie();
               request.setAttribute("movies", Movie.getAllMovies());
               out.println(request.getAttribute("movies"));
   }


 }
```

**Movie.java**

```
package movie;
public class Movie {
String s;
   public Movie(){
      s="hello zDoctor";   
   }
   public String getAllMovies(){
       return s;
   }
}
```

[servlet output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PdtE.png)

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8ZHw.png)

Comment: hello, thanks for the response and sorry its taken so long to reply. I believe i'm not compiling the code correctly then.